# How to put a colour listview in an alertdialog, with the leading as the colour

Tags: flutter, colors, flutter-alertdialog

Hello my problem is about building a good `alertdialog`.

i have a Listtile `Listtile` where the `leading` is a color and the `title` is the name of the colour.
on tap the `Listtile` shows a alert dialog with colour options.

this is what i am expecting to archieve.

[image]
[image]

i found this solution from a page but the code was really hard to scale.

i am expecting to archieve this result by using a map on the colours and printing them as `Listview` on the alert dialog. thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this question how to send something to another page ?

Based on comment, you want to pass color with their names. So it could be pass to the second screen like this.

The first page,

```
var colors = {};
colors['color_x'] = 'COLORX';
colors['color_y'] = 'COLORY';

Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => SecondScreen(colors: colors),
  ),
);
```

In the second page,

```
class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map colors;

  SecondScreen({Key key, @required this.colors}) : super(key: key);
  ...
}
```

Comment: yes but it's more about sending a color with it's name to another page. for now i can send the color but not the name of the color. for now my approach is to keep the colors in a `_colorcolection` list . and the  color names in a `_colornames`list then with a `int` called `_selectedcolor` i can choose the color and the name at the same time . But in page 1 I only need the color and when i send the information to page 2 i can't extract the index (in this case `_selectedcolor`) of the color because i am recieving only the color from page 1.

Comment: @ANDREWEBARE 
I think blackkara's answer is correct, you can pass as a parameter a map that has key: color name and value: color

Comment: hello @blackkara the help was really useful to me, but i found that my biggest problem is the `alertdialog` it self, can you help me please recreate an `alertdialog` where the leading is the same color as the `title` of the `listview`? or help me with some hints thank you

Answer (score 0):

- Create enum: `enum ColorEnum {red, green, blue}`
- Page 2: `Navigator.of(context).pop(ColorEnum.red);`
- If you using Dialog call .then after it:

  showDialog().then(colorValue){
  //your code
  };
- If you using Navigator to push new page: using .then after it:

  Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (context) => SecondScreen(colors: colors),
  ),
  ).then(colorValue){//yourcode}